# Fail with nexted includes

Tags: php, nested, include

I have a script that includes a file and that file has an include in it, like this:

In script:

```
    include('includes/functions/homepage.php);
```

In homepage.php:

```
    include('includes/functions/parent_functions.php');
```

I searched here and see it is a very common problem and the solution seems to be to use

```
    include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/functions/homepage.php');
```

I have the above and still get this error:

Warning: include(includes/functions/parent_functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I've tried this on a site running php 5.5 and another using 7.2 - fails the same on both. If I print the path using the following it shows the correct full path.

```
    echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/functions/homepage.php';
```

As mentioned, this is a common question here but the fix isn't working in my case. Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have an issue here. As the parent_functions.php and homepage.php are in the same directory you need not put an extra directory prefix. You can simply use

```
 include('parent_functions.php');
```

instead of

```
include('includes/functions/parent_functions.php');
```

Comment: This script will be used in many sites. Is the only way to get it to work is to have everyone that uses it change the code in their shops? If so, then I will need to abandon this idea.

Comment: homepage.php can never have include('includes/functions/parent_functions.php'); because this will search another "includes/functions" directory from the directory where homepage.php is located. Hence you will end up with an error

Comment: This is strange. The existing homepage.php file is in many sites and has worked like that for years. And in the docs for includes, it states, " ...include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing". So it sounds like it should work as is. But I removed the path in that file and my script works, as you said it would. I will change my code to not require that file to get around this, though it is curious, to me at least, why it only fails with my script. Thank you for your help.